# Signing the Certificate signing request of a client in python

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate, csr

Suppose I would like to sign a `csr` received from a client, and then give it back to him.

The client might use the following source code to generate a csr.

source : https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa


# Generate client key
client_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048
)

# Generate a CSR

csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"California"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"San Francisco"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"My Company"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"mysite.com"),
])).add_extension(

    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        # Describe what sites we want this certificate for.
        x509.DNSName(u"mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName(u"www.mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName(u"subdomain.mysite.com"),
    ]),

    critical=False,

# Sign the CSR with our private key.
).sign(client_key, hashes.SHA256())

# Write our CSR out to disk.
with open("cert.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

Then, the client might pass the `csr` to the `CA` for its signature.
Load the csr and give it to the CA

```
with open("cert.pem", "rb") as pem:
        pem_csr = pem.read()
```

The CA receives the `pem_csr` and signs it.

```
### CA
# Generate CA key
key_ca = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048
)
    
laod_client_csr = x509.load_pem_x509_csr(load_pem_csr)
```

How could I get CA signature on the `laod_client_csr` ?

Comment: As with your other post, unfortunately I don't understand the question *How could I get CA signature on the laod_client_csr*. The CA does **not** sign the CSR since the CSR is already signed by the applicant. The CA checks the CSR, creates a certificate based on the information in the CSR, **signs this certificate** (not the CSR!) with its private key, and sends the certificate to the applicant.

Comment: Ok @Topaco. Does that mean that the CA should receive information such as `COUNTRY_NAME, STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, , LOCALITY_NAME, ORGANIZATION_NAME,  COMMON_NAME,` and the `public key of the applicant` (If using the crypto library) , then creates a `csr` based on that, signs it with its private key (`CA private key`) and send the certificate back to the applicant ?

Comment: Also, when you say `The CA checks the CSR`, do you mean the CA receives information about the applicant to create and sign a certificate ?

Comment: @Topaco On the webpage `https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr`, they created a `csr` by signing it with the applicant private key. Then they say: `Now we can give our CSR to a CA, who will give a certificate to us in return.` How will the CA sign that certificate, as it has already been signed by the applicant with the applicant private key ?

Comment: _How will the CA sign that certificate, as it has already been signed by the applicant with the applicant private key?_ You seem to be confusing CSR and certificate. CSR and certificate are two different things. The CSR is the request to get a certificate from a CA. The CSR is created and signed by the applicant, and sent to the CA. The certificate is created and signed by the CA, and sent to the applicant. Take a look at the workflow between applicant and CA on the web, e.g. https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-certificate-authority/.

Comment: @Topaco thank you for the resource. Regarding the `crytography library` I don't see the public key be used by the applicant to generate a CSR. source `https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr`. However, using the `crypto library` one can set `client_cert.set_pubkey(client_key)`. Source: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873832/how-do-i-create-and-sign-certificates-with-pythons-pyopenssl#45886729`. Why don't we use the `public key` when considering the  `crytography library`?

Comment: This line confuses me : `# Sign the CSR with our private key: 

).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())` Source: `https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr` . Applicant seems to use its private key to sign a CSR before sending it to a CA

Comment: 1st: The public key is contained in the private key, so that the public key can be determined from the private key that is used for signing. This is how the *Cryptography* library does it. Look at the CSR in an ASN.1 parser (e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/), then you will find the public key there.

Comment: 2nd: Signing is *always* done with the private key (the public key is used for encryption). Don't confuse public and private keys: In the CSR, the *public* key of the applicant is sent to the CA (which proves ownership of the *public* key in the certificate - that's the whole point of a certificate). However, for the signature of the CSR, the *private* key of the applicant is used. Please familiarize yourself with the basics, SO is not the right place for this.

Comment: If you don't sign the CSR with the private key of the key pair then an advisory can perform a man in the middle where they change some of the data fields in the certificate. Of course, you would generally use a trusted channel nowadays, but hey, more is better when it comes to security. Note too that many of the fields of the CSR are copied, but the CA adds fields to it, e.g. the not before / after fields, the CRL location etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a straightforward example is missing on the documentation and google leads here. If you understand that a CSR is basically something that just contains information, the following makes sense.

Here's a minimal example that should be helpful.

```py
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# create ca key
ca_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
)

# create ca subject/issuer which are the same (self-signed)
ca_subject = ca_issuer = x509.Name([
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"World"),
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"The Internet"),
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"StackExchange"),
])
ca_cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
    ca_subject
).issuer_name(
    ca_issuer
).public_key(
    ca_key.public_key()
).serial_number(
    x509.random_serial_number()
).not_valid_before(
    datetime.utcnow()
).not_valid_after(
    datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=2)
).add_extension(
    x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True
).sign(ca_key, hashes.SHA256())

# now we have the self-signed CA cert + CA key


# create CSR with a different key

key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
)

cert_subject = x509.Name([
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"World"),
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"The Internet"),
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"Stackoverflow"),
   x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"stackoverflow.com"),
])

# create a CSR signed with our key

csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(
    cert_subject
).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())

# create a certificate from CSR, getting the information from CSR
# and signing with the CA key

cert = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
    csr.subject
).issuer_name(
    ca_cert.subject
).public_key(
    csr.public_key()
).serial_number(
    x509.random_serial_number()
).not_valid_before(
    datetime.utcnow()
).not_valid_after(
    datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
).sign(ca_key, hashes.SHA256())

# Now "cert" will verify successfully against the "ca_cert"
```

So this means you have to pass information from the CSR manually as I do not see an interface on `CertificateBuilder` that accepts a CSR. I.e. if you want to have SAN extension:

```py
import ipaddress

...

# add it to the CSR

csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder()
  ...
.add_extension(
  x509.SubjectAlternativeName(
    [x509.IPAddress(ipaddress.ipaddress('127.0.0.1'))],
  ),
  critical=False,
)
  ...

...

# pass it from CSR to CertificateBuilder

cert = x509.CertificateBuilder()
  ...

for ext in csr.extensions:
  cert = cert.add_extension(ext.value, critical=ext.critical)

cert = cert.sign(...)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the final loop that blindly copies all extensions from the CSR into the final certificate should not be used.

If the certificate owner who created the CSR included a Basic Constraints extension with CA set to True and a non-zero path, then the signed certificate would itself become a CA certificate and could be used to sign unlimited amounts of further valid certificates.